# Name for threaded workbench receptacles?

Tags: tabletop, workbench, clamps

I was given a portable wooden workbench with several holes drilled into it, and on the inside of each of these holes is what I would call a "*screw receptacle*"; essentially metal, threaded "female" receptable that would allow someone to screw a bolt or perhaps a clamp down in the middle of the table.

**Anybody know what the proper term for these threaded "screw receptacles" might be?**

Comment: Are you looking for the term "threaded inserts"? There are many kinds. Here is one example: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Hillman-2-Count-1-4-in-Brass-Standard-SAE-Wood-Insert-Lock-Nuts/3012573

Comment: Ah nice, I think so! @CharlieKilian do you know if anyone makes *big* inserts (3/4" or even 7/8")?

Comment: Do you mean 3/4" length, or 3/4" diameter? I've seen long threaded inserts, but not threaded inserts with such a large diameter. They might exist somewhere, but I'd be concerned that anything you might screw into it would have enough torque or leverage to pull the insert right out. You might be able to get away with tapping the wood directly. What is this for? There might be other ways to accomplish what you're wanting, too.

Comment: It sounds like you're talking about hardware for making your own bench vise.  Try looking for a "flange nut".  Also be careful to note if it's acme thread or standard...

Comment: This is for screwing in the pegs of a standard [armwrestling table](http://www.armsport.com/tablespecs.htm) which will require an enormous amount of sturdiness and resilience and which will need to withstand hundreds of pounds of force.

Comment: Do you have any standard bolts that fit the threading? I was thinking initially that what you're describing might be the metal collar that some commercial hold-downs use, but those aren't threaded they're just grooved.